Quadratic equations with a common root - does the argument work both ways?
Here is a question from the Cambridge University 1st year examination from 1889:
Prove that if $a+b+c=0$ then each pair of the equations $x^{2}+ax+bc=0$, $x^{2}+bx+ac=0$ and $x^{2}+cx+ab=0$ will have a common root.
I am curious if the argument works in reverse - if the three equations have a common root, will it always be true that $a+b+c=0$.
It seems to make logical sense, but if anyone has a counter-example I would be keen to see it.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

Thanks Anne - this is not a "no clue" question.

It is. To understand why and remedy it, please follow the 2nd link above.

This is a much easier question than the original problem.
If two polynomials $P, \, Q$ have a root $\alpha$ in common, then $\alpha$ is also a root of $P-Q$. In our case
$$ (x^2+ax+bc)-(x^2+bx+ac) = (a-b)(x-c). $$
If the first two equations have a common root, it must be $c$. In particular, one has
$$ 0 = c^2+ac+bc = c(a+b+c). $$
Repeating the argument with the other two couples we get either $a=b=c=0$ or the claim directly.
